# Passing data from conditional/chained drop boxes in a form to a view or directly to URL

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am in the process of implementing a feature to allow users to query, through a set of conditional drop boxes, to find other users by grouping. For example, my drop downs chain from `Departments`->`Teams`->`Users`. I have that part setup correctly, but I can't figure out how to use the data from the last (`Users`) to either send it to my view or redirect the user to a URL. If the user is `test` I want to send them to `http://example.com/user/test` or I want to send them to my view which accepts `user` as a parameter. I have a `FormView`, form, and 2 functions which work with Ajax to get the conditional drop boxes. See below for my code:

Views.py

```
class UserQuery(FormView):
    template_name = 'people/users_form.html'
    model = People
    form_class = UsersListForm

def load_teams(request):
    department = request.GET.get('department')
    teams = Teams.objects.filter(department=department).order_by('team')
    return render(request, 'people/team_dropdown_list_options.html', {'teams': teams})


def load_users(request):
    team = request.GET.get('team')
    people = People.objects.filter(team=team).order_by('people')
    return render(request, 'people/people_dropdown_list_options.html', {'people': people})


def load_one(request):
    selected_person = request.GET.get('people')
    one = People.objects.get(id=selected_person).people
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'username': one})
```

So `load_one()` has the data I need. It has the username that I want to pass to `http://example.com/user/{}` -- I have a view already for that URL, but I need to figure out how to get them there any the form is submitted. Right now it seems like I am using the FormView incorrectly as it wants to create something, rather than just query.

Forms.py

```
class PeopleListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['team'].queryset = Teams.objects.none()
        self.fields['people'].queryset = People.objects.none()


        if 'department' in self.data:
            try:
                department_id = int(self.data.get('department'))
                self.fields['team'].queryset = Teams.objects.filter(department=department_id).order_by('team')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['team'].queryset = self.instance.department.team_set.order_by('team')

        if 'team' in self.data:
            try:
                team_id = int(self.data.get('team'))
                self.fields['people'].queryset = Employees.objects.filter(team=team_id).order_by('people')
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['people'].queryset = self.instance.department.team_set.order_by('people')


        if 'people' in self.data:
            try:
                people_id = int(self.data.get('people'))
                self.fields['people'].queryset = People.objects.get(id=people_id).people
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass
        elif self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['people'].queryset = self.instance.team.people

    class Meta:
        model = People
        fields = ('department', 'team', 'people')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^query/$', EmployeeSurveyQuery.as_view(), name='survey-options'),
    url(r'^ajax/load_teams/$', load_teams, name='ajax-load-teams'),
    url(r'^ajax/load_users/$', load_users, name='ajax-load-users'),
    url(r'^ajax/load_one/$', load_one, name='ajax-load-one'),
    url(r'^user/(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/$', user_page, name='user-page'),
]
```